# shell script to trigger a command with every new line in to a file?

Tags: linux, shell, email, logging

Is it possible to trigger a command with every new line in to a file?

For example: I have a log file say maillog. I want to get every new entry in to the log file as a mail.

If a new entry like " Mail Sent " added in to maillog file then my script should grep the new entry and send me a mail with the entry(data).

I know its crazy but i want to automate my Linux box with these kind of things.

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not so crazy.  Check periodically (once per hour, per day, what you like) the file for new parts by storing the original length of the file, compare the length, in case it has grown, handle the part which was appended:

```
length=0
while sleep 3600  # use wanted delay here
do
  new_length=$(find "$file" -printf "%s")
  if [ $length -lt $new_length ]
  then
    tail --bytes=$[new_length-length] "$file" | handle_part
  fi
  length=$new_length
done
```

Now you only have to write that `handle_part` function which could for instance mail its input somewhere.

Using this way (instead of the obvious `tail -f`) has the advantage that you can store the current length into a file and later on restarting your script read that length again.  So you won't get the whole file after a restart of your script (e. g. due to a machine reboot).

If you want a faster response you could have a look at `inotify` which is a facility on Linux to monitor file actions; so that polling could be replaced.

Comment: Hi Alfe.. thanks it worked for my requirement. I had 2 modifications in the code.

Comment: One is at if $[ $length -lt $new_length ] it gave syntax error. I removed $ and tried  if [ $length -lt $new_length ]. it worked.

Comment: Second is the first length value is changed to avoid entire file contents sent in mail...

Comment: Pardon me for multiple comments.... Again thanks Alfe and larsmans for the timely replies and help...

Comment: Yeah, right, sorry, that $ was out of place there (edited my solution accordingly).  And if an answer suits you, you should accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Use `tail -f`, that watches a file and sents whatever is appended to it to `stdout`. If you have a script that performs the desired action, say `mail_per_line`, then you can set it up as

```
tail -f maillog | mail_per_line
```

In this case, `mail_per_line` runs once and gets all the lines. If you want to spawn a separate process each time a line comes in, use the shell built-in `read`:

```
tail -f maillog | while IFS='' read line; do
    send_a_message "$line"
done
```

To counter the effect described by Alfe, that a restart of this program will cause all the previous logs to be processed again, consider using [logrotate](http://man.cx/logrotate).

Comment: Consider appearing chunks of several lines.  Your solution will send them in separate mails, each containing just one line.

Comment: @Alfe: true, and that's exactly the OP's requirement.

Comment: If you choose to interpret him this way — so be it.  I found it more interesting to understand the "entries" he talks about to be possibly multiline, even if he wants to trigger the sending by new lines.

Comment: @Alfe it's pretty explicit: "trigger a command with every new line in to [sic] a file". For more structured processing, my first suggestion + logrotate can be a simple solution.

Comment: Each new line could trigger it and still send whole chunks in the end.  But that's not the point.  The question is what the user probably would like, no matter how he tried to put it in words.